# GKE Web Application Network Access Control

Tags: google-cloud-platform, web-applications, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

We want to deploy a Web Application on GKE. We want this application to be accessible only from the company's network. It should not accessible from internet. Are there any guidelines to implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any hybrid connection between your office/company network and Google Cloud using something like CloudVPN Or Dedicated Interconnect ? In other terms do you have a direct connection between your Company Network and a VPC somewhere in GCP ?

If yes you can use Internal LoadBalancers to expose the Webapp only to your internal Network

If not Google Cloud Loadbalancers (Aka l7) + Cloud Armor and you can configure Cloud Armor to only allow the Egress IP of your office network (Assuming it's a fixed NAT IP) to talk to that LoadBalancer.